# ios: I need to fill half of UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, graphics

I have a UIImage of a [image: star].

I need to fill half of it with blue color programmatically.
I try this:

```
extension UIImage {

public func maskWithColor(color: UIColor, factor: CGFloat) -> UIImage 
{

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 
        self.size.width/2, height: self.size.height), false, 
        self.scale)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size)

        color.setFill()
        self.draw(in: rect)

        context.setBlendMode(.sourceIn)
        context.fill(rect)

        let resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return resultImage
    }

}
```

And result of it: 
  [image: Half stars]

But result like:
[image: this]

I need one half - blue and other gray. How I can do this?

Comment: Just use this bro: https://github.com/evgenyneu/Cosmos

Comment: Or use [PaintCode](https://www.paintcodeapp.com)

Comment: use MGStarRatingView ,
https://github.com/magi82/MGStarRatingView
 , 
 MGStarRatingView is a view for rating.
Simple and easy to implement. 

It supports programmatically and xib.
No image is required. Just choose color.

Answer (score 0):

Install this pod

```
pod 'Cosmos', '~> 17.0'
```

Use like this

1) Drag View object from the Object Library into your storyboard.
Add view control in attributes inspector
[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmQOq.png)

2) Set the view's class to CosmosView in the Identity Inspector. Set its module property to Cosmos if you used Carthage or CocoaPods setup methods.
Add Cosmos rating view to the storyboard
[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EAIq.png)

3) Customize the Cosmos view appearance in the Attributes Inspector. If storyboard does not show the stars click Refresh All Views from the Editor menu.
Customize cosmos appearance in the attributes inspector in Xcode.
[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyerF.png)